# Find the interconnected ids in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array of objects that represent connections by id between objects that are being used in a D3 force directed graph. The source and target keys both represent ids. It looks something like this:

```
var links: [
{ source: 1, target: 0 }, 
{ source: 1, target: 2 }, 
{ source: 1, target: 3 }, 
{ source: 1, target: 4 }, 
{ source: 1, target: 5 }, 
{ source: 2, target: 3 }, 
{ source: 2, target: 4 }, 
{ source: 2, target: 5 }, 
{ source: 3, target: 4 }, 
{ source: 3, target: 5 }, 
{ source: 4, target: 5 }, 
{ source: 6, target: 7 }, 
{ source: 8, target: 7 }, 
{ source: 9, target: 7 }, 
{ source: 7, target: 0 } ]
```

Ids 1 through 5 are interconnected to each other in such a way that when rendered in d3, you would see them form a 5-pointed star like they do here: http://jsfiddle.net/6DTMp/

How would you iterate over this array to find the objects that are interconnected with each other in the same way that ids 1 through 5 are? The end result that I'm looking for is to have an array of ids that make up the nodes on the D3 graph that form the 5 pointed star.

Comment: `id` as in in what part of each object, the `source` || `target` ?

Comment: Both source and target are the ids. 1 is connected to 2, 1 to 3, 1 to 4, 1 to 5, 2 to 3, 2 to 4, 2 to 5, etc etc.

Comment: So what is your expected result? An array with the neighbours of each node?

Comment: @juvian Updated the answer with the end result, which is an array of ids that make up the nodes on the D3 graph that form the 5 pointed star.

Answer (score 0):

I'd iterate over the edges with for/in and store everything I see in an object that maps ids to list of adjacent nodes.

Something like that.

```
var map = {};
for( var k in links ) {
    var src = links[k].source;
    var tgt = links[k].target;

    if( typeof map[src] === "undefined" ) {
        map[src] = [];
    }
    map[src].push(tgt);

    if( typeof map[tgt] === "undefined" ) {
        map[tgt] = [];
    }
    map[tgt].push(src);
}
```

Comment: you are missing `var map=[];`

Comment: That's one of steps to finding a solution however it falls short of determining which ids are "interconnected" to each other, which will ultimately leaves some ids out of the map itself.

Comment: And by interconnected you mean not directly but over other nodes, e.g. if 1 <-> 2 and 2 <-> 3 then 1 <-> 3 should appear in the result?

Comment: @Martin By interconnected, I mean the ids that are all connected to each other. In this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6DTMp/) you can see that five nodes that have connections to each other. Since they are all connected to each other, they form a star.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to find "complete subgraphs" in a graph, where complete means, all vertices are directly connected to each other. You should probably have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem